# Remove 'T' from date time and convert into sql date

Tags: java, postgresql, datetime

I have json field as

```
{"dateTime" : "2018-06-02T15:49:23"}
```

Now I need to use this field in a postgres stored procedure as an input parameter. In SP the input field type is timestamp as I need to convert this dateTime in sql timestamp without 'T' in between (just 2018-06-02 15:49:23).
Any suggestions on how do I achieve it in Java is much appreciated.

Comment: `select ('{"dateTime" : "2018-06-02T15:49:23"}'::json->>'dateTime')::timestamp` - you can just select it, no need to parse in Java

Comment: Rather than just removing the `T` I recommend you parse the string into a `LocalDateTime` in Java (the one-arg `LocalDateTime.parse` method does that) and pass the `LocalDateTime` to your stored procedure.

Comment: @Ole yes.! LocalDateTime worked for me here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than just removing the `T` I recommend you parse the string into a `LocalDateTime` in Java. The one-arg `LocalDateTime.parse` method does that:

```
    LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse("2018-06-02T15:49:23");
```

Then you can pass the `LocalDateTime` to your stored procedure where it expects a timestamp.

```
    CallableStatement cs = yourConnection.prepareCall("{call your_stored_procedure(?)}");
    cs.setObject(1, dateTime);
```

In the old days we would have used a `java.sql.Timestamp` here. That class is now long outdated. With Java 8 and JDBC 4.2 or higher we prefer to use either a `LocalDateTime` or an `Instant`.

Answer (score 0):

you can just select it:

```
t=# select ('{"dateTime" : "2018-06-02T15:49:23"}'::json->>'dateTime')::timestamp;
      timestamp
---------------------
 2018-06-02 15:49:23
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.json.*;

... let's obj is your var that contain your JSON with datetime
String dateTime= obj.getString("dateTime");

DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss");
DateTime dateTime = f.parseDateTime(dateTime);

Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(dt.getMillis()); /*if you need in milliseconds*/
```

Comment: Using Joda-Time?